# Как создать функцию, которая получает число, а возвращает список всех возможных перестановок знаков между цифрами, в результате которых выходит 100?

Tags: python

Создать функцию, которая для заданного числа возвращает список всех возможных расстановок знаков арифметических операций и скобок между его цифрами таким образом, чтобы в результате выполнения этих операций в соответствии с правилами получалось число 100.
Для упрощения вычислений можно предположить, что первоначальное число передается в функцию в строковом виде. Например, для вызова такой функции со строкой "123456" должен получиться ответ:

```
["(1 +  ((2 +  (3 +  4)) * (5 +  6)))",
"(1 +  (((2 +  3) +  4) * (5 +  6)))"]
```

Насколько сложна эта задача и как ее можно реализовать на python?

Comment: Я почти уверен, что эта задача не решается никак, кроме полного перебора. Но просто так все возможные расстановки не перебрать, поэтому можно попробовать использовать обратную польскую нотацию или деревья арифметических выражений (вот тут второй рисунок - пример такого дерева: http://aliev.me/runestone/Trees/ParseTree.html)

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все-таки я предполагал, что это потребует больших усилий, когда писал комментарий.

```
opers = ['+', '-', '*']

def all_var(leafes):
    global opers
    
    if len(leafes) == 0:
        return []
    if len(leafes) == 1:
        return [leafes]
    
    res = []
    for op in opers:
        for i in range(len(leafes) - 1):
            t = leafes[:i] + [f'({leafes[i]} {op} {leafes[i + 1]})'] + leafes[i + 2:]
            res += all_var(t)

    return res


s = '123456'
a = list(s)
n = 100

res = set([i[0] for i in all_var(a) if eval(i[0]) == n])
for i in res:
    print(i)
```

Если обратиться к тем самым синтаксическим деревьям, о которых я упоминал в комментарии, то изначально мы имеем 6 листов: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`. Причем операция может быть произведена только между соседними листьями (очевидно, мы не можем сложить 1 и 3, никак не взаимодействуя с двойкой). Это дает возможность для данного набора листьев перебрать все возможные варианты постановки первого знака.

Далее по свойствам синтаксических деревьев, мы можем сказать, будто этих двух выбранных листьев никогда не существовало, а на их месте всегда был результат операции над ними:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 -> 1 2 (3 + 4) 5 6 -> 1 2 7 5 6`.

Тогда мы получаем новый набор листьев, длина которого на 1 меньше, а значит мы можем использовать рекурсивную функцию перебора.

Разумеется, она очень тяжела по вычислительной сложности (для строки длины 7 уже выполняется секунд 9-10 на моем компьютере), однако она создает все возможные варианты расстановки знаков, насколько я могу судить.

Comment: спасибо огромное за такую работу, я даже не ожидал)